# DOMGenerationError: Binding value inconsistent with content model

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyxb

While constructing xml using pyxb module, I am getting the error as "DOMGenerationError: Binding value inconsistent with content model".

Is it possible to know what is the exact error message causing above problem?

Answer (score 0):

That error message was removed two years ago tomorrow, prior to release of PyXB 1.2, which has significantly better diagnostic capability.  Without knowing which version of PyXB you're using I can't suggest a specific solution, but if you update to 1.2.4 the techniques [in the documentation](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_validating.html) would probably help a lot.